# WCF - Validation of the Service to the Client

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

Imagine a self hosted WCF service, and a client that connects via a proxy.

Is it possible to implement custom validation of service credentials from within the client? i.e. Is it possible to validate the custom service user name and password?  It's very easy to set up custom validation of client credentials in a service host but I'm not sure if it's possible to do it the other way around.

Thanks for reading.

Chris.

Comment: Service doesn't send user name and password to the client. What you mean is probably UserPrincipal which is validated in Active directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can achieve what I'm after by customising the service identity and validating that at the client.